# Python - Get list of users in a Discord Server

Tags: python, discord

Hi I have a Discord Bot set up and I have a Flask application running as well.

Is there anyway to get data of my discord server using something like the Discord API or Webhook?

Answer (score 0):

For users, you have [`guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)

Further, you can iterate over it and get their `name` and `discriminator`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a command that gets you all the members and then you can get their length and send it to the flask application.

```
@client.command()
async def get_members(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    #This will get you all the members in your server
    for user in list(ctx.guild.members):
        print(user)
        #You can do whatever you want here
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, the only convenient way of passing your bot info to a website is to have an instance of a bot running simultaneously (You could, of course, also make native API calls, but I wouldn't recommend that). So as soon as you start your flask application, you would also have to initialize an instance of your bot.

Your bot, by default, fetches [certain information](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) on initialization, such as the servers it's on. You should be able to present that information then to your website.
You can also use the `client.get_...` methods to gain additional information.

So, if you flask app needs certain information, you could initialize your client, create functions like

```py
def get_guild_names():
    return [guild.name for guild in client.guilds]
```

and then call them from your flask application.